# Cursor/typing caret doesn't show when moved around in Word 2019

Tags: microsoft-word, mouse

I'm using Word 2019 on Windows 10, and have recently ran into a problem.

When I get past a certain page length in Print Layout (or perhaps word counts, not sure how it's calculate), the screen will blink once, then went back to normal (henceforth referred to as the Flashpoint). Everything still work as it should, but for some reason, the cursor (the blinking vertical line to indicate where you're typing) will start acting weird. Here's how:

1. If I start typing, moving it with an arrow, highlighting, whatever that **makes the cursor move away from the original position**, it turned invisible. Functionally, nothing is amiss, I just can't see where it is
2. If I **use the mouse to click to any random spot**, the cursor will appear again, and stay visible until I move it around as stated above.
3. **Moving** **up past the Flashpoint** will also make the cursor visible again, and I can move it around like normal without it disappearing (as long as I don't go down past Flashpoint).
4. If I **zoom out**, the Flashpoint is seemingly pushed further downward. The cursor will be visible and act like normal for many more page, but if I go down past a certain point, it's Flashpoint Paradox all over again. If I zoom out further, the Flashpoint is again pushed downward.
5. If I switch to **draft view**, the problem went away completely. No more Flashpoint, no more disappearing cursor.
6. This is **NOT document-specific**. Any new document that's long enough (regardless of template) will run into the same issue.

So far I've tried rebooting, copy the content to a new document (no formatting), convert document to .doc file, turned off and on Use Smart Cursor, and nothing work.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Has your normal.dotx been modified in any way?

Comment: Actually, the template that I use is normal.dotm. Does this have any bearing on the problem?

Comment: Not sure - has it been modified since it was installed?  Check installation date vs last modified date of normal.dotm.  I normally write protect the normal.dot* files.  It stops you accidentally saving stuff to it and affecting all other docs.  Also stops some viruses from infecting all documents.

Comment: FYI: it just happened to in Word 365 that the caret is not visible, ever. Then I switched to Draft mode and it reappeared. Switched back to Print Layout and it is still there. I experienced this for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a setting called "Use smart cursoring" in Word Options>Advanced that can cause this issue.

Comment: What should be done with this setting? Should it be on or off?

Comment: Where is this setting please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which really drove me crazy. Finally I found the real reason. Simply turn off the "HDR" display mode will solve it.

Comment: Where is this setting please?